# Firebase 7-day active users different in Firebase Analytics compared to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I've been trying to calculate figures for the 7-day active users from Firebase apps by using the BigQuery export, counting the number of distinct `user_pseudo_id` who logged a `user_interaction` event in the given period. When doing this, the 7-day figures as displayed in the Firebase Console are consistently higher than the figures calculated using BigQuery. However, the 1-day active users match.

As an example, the query I'm running for 1-day active users is:

```
SELECT 
  event_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS active_users
FROM `<project>.analytics_X.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20200525' AND '20200531'
AND event_name = 'user_engagement'
GROUP BY event_date
```

and for the total number of active users in this period:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS active_users
FROM `<project>.analytics_X.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20200525' AND '20200531'
AND event_name = 'user_engagement'
```

The results in the first query matches the 1-day figures in the chart in Firebase Analytics console, for each date from 25th of May until 31st of May. In the second query, the value of `active_users` is 13915. In Firebase Console however, the 7-day active users value on the 31st of May is 14069.

This is only a small deviation of around 1%. More significantly, the percentage difference of 7-day active users compared to previous 7 days period, is -5.5% on the Firebase Console but when computing this difference by running 7-day period queries for successive periods (`20200525` to `20200531` and `20200518` to `20200524`) the difference turned out to be -6.3%.

[Number of active users (1-day, 7-day, 28-day), compared to the previous 7-day period, in Firebase Console on May 31st.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJWne.png)

What could be the reason for this discrepancy? Am I missing something? Appreciate any help.

Comment: The issue can be that data for the most recent 3 days might still be uploaded to BigQuery due to late data, which will is uploaded to BigQuery once per day. So, this can cause some count discrepancy between Firebase and BigQuery. Also, can you confirm that you are checking the result comparison for the same dates? Because if the count per day in BigQuery is equal to the count per day in Firebase. Then the total sum should be equal too. Did it help you?

Comment: I also suspected it could be related to the delay in data upload. However I double checked with the 1-day counts and those matched, which indeed seems strange. Also I checked 7-day counts for some periods that ended more than 3 days ago, and the discrepancy was there for those as well - always with a higher count observed on Firebase Analytics than in BigQuery. So the issue seems to be somewhere else...

Comment: So, if you check the data for 1 day period (for data older than 3 days), the results match the Firebase but, they don't match the values in when counting for a 7 days period, right? This discrepancy should not happen if the count per day matches. Also, are you using StandardSQL?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'm using StandardSQL.

Comment: Can you confirm that for each date the count is equal in BigQuery and in Firebase? As I said previously, if the count is equal daily it should be equal in a range of time too ( if it is not for the past 3 days because data may still arrive).

Comment: Yeah, checked now again, today is 10th of June. I checked the interval 31st of May until 6th of June. BigQuery 7-day count is 14543, in Firebase Console it is 14708. The 1-day figures in this period are 2270, 2805, 2999, 3205, 3230, 3552, 3007, and they exactly match between BigQuery and the Firebase Console.

Comment: if you sum up all the daily values you shared, the result is 21068, which is different fro the 7-day count, you mentioned. Are you checking the sum for the same week?

Comment: Yeah, the 1-day values cannot be summed up like that because the aggregates are not additive across days (the same user_pseudo_id might be present on multiple days). The distinct counts therefore need to be computed separately for each time interval.